# How to differentiate similar looking path parameters in endpoint URLs

Tags: api, rest, endpoint

I am trying to design a REST API endpoint that has 2 dynamic path parameters whose values can have similar lengths. Example shown below where the base path is /retry.

```
/retry/<param1> and 
/retry/<param2>
```

param1 can take UTF-8 strings of size 10 while param2 can take UTF-8 of size 10 as well.So as a result there is no structural distinction between param1 and param2.

I am looking for the most elegant way to design the endpoint that has these params as a part of the dynamic URL path and the URLs in both cases can be distinguished from each other.

Some ideas I came across are something like this

```
/retry/param1-<value of param1> and 
/retry/param2-<value of param2>
```

But I have never seen this approach been undertaken before in API design and to my view it makes the endpoint slightly messy and hard to manage.

I could have added these params as a query parameter instead, but the requirements need me to specify these as path parameters.

Are there better ways to achieve this design requirement?

Comment: `/retry/param1/<value>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Reminder: REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers.

Which is good: it means that we can use the extra degrees of freedom to choose a spelling convention that human beings can stand.

A good reference when looking for URI design inspiration is [RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570.html), because if you see a design there that you like, it is likely that your implementation language of choice will have a library that does the general purpose work for you.

So: as noted by Rotem, you might be able to distinguish identifiers because they have a difference sequence of segments.

```
/retry/param1/x
/retry/param2/y
```

If the extra segment is unacceptable, then we need to look for alternatives that allow us to distinguish two segments.

URI level 3 template support includes [path style parameter expansion](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570.html#section-3.2.7) which includes a mechanism for expanding key-value pairs.

```
/retry/param;1=x
/retry/param;2=y
```

Of course, you could also just describe the two different identifier schemes using two different templates and simple variable expansion

```
/retry/param1=x
/retry/param2=y
```